# Is it possible to have multiple log files for one rsnapshot?

Tags: log-files, rsnapshot

the company im working for use rsnapshot for its backup. I know where to put the log path in the conf file, but i was wondering if it was possible to have something like :

```
/var/log/rsnapshot  --> for normal snapshot
/var/log/rsnapshot.err  --> for when an error occur
```

We are running 20 hourly backup, so it gets very tedious to search for errors and would be much easier to just have a file for those.

Thanks

Comment: I don't use rsnapshot, so i don't know log file format. But it seems that some people manage this issue using something like this in crontab : "cat /var/log/rsnapshot.log | grep ERROR >errorlog"